# HoldForm print out defined variables

Tags: manipulate

I'm not sure if this is possible or not but I'm looking to use, the print function with somesort of function like HoldForm. The only issue here is it doesn't print out the defined variables (see photo below):

[image]

Is anyone aware if it's possible to print out the variable and the sum without it doing the calculation? For example I need for an exam situation and therefore need to show the sum/calculation itself and not just the result.

Hope it makes sense!

Thanks,
Charlotte:)

Comment: In addition to the picture, please provide the code in Mathematica format, so that users can copy it.  Also, it is not clear to me what "it doesn't print out the defined variables " means.

Comment: It would be helpful if you give the form you want the result to appear (for the exams, or whatever).  As a minor comment, you do not need to turn your expressions into a string and then use `Print`. Consider, for example, the following construct: `H == Inactive[Sum][HoldForm[i[[t]] /(1 + R)^t], {t, 1, 3}] // TraditionalForm`.

Answer (score 4):

In order to substitute the value of one variable into a held expression, you can do something like the following:

```
a = 2;
b = 3;
With[{a = a}, Hold[a + b]]

(* Hold[2 + b] *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = {10, 15, 25};
R = 0.425;
s = Sum[Part[i, t]/(1 + R)^t, {t, 3}];
t = Defer@Sum[Part[i, t]/(1 + R)^t, {t, 3}];

Print["H = ", t, " = ", s]
```

$$\text{H = }\sum _t^3 \frac{i[[t]]}{(R+1)^t}\text{ = }23.0441$$